# unary negation in parsing java

Tags: java, parsing, cup

What I am trying to do is allowing expression like 8 - - - 2 + 3.

```
program ::= expr:e
            {: RESULT = ...; :}
         ;

expr ::= INTCONST:c
         {: RESULT = ...; :}
      |  binaryExpr:e
         {: RESULT = e;   :}
      |  LPAREN expr:e RPAREN
         {: RESULT = e;   :}
      |  MINUS expr:e               
         {: RESULT = - e; :}
         %prec UMINUS
      ;

binaryExpr ::= expr:e1 PLUS expr:e2
               {: RESULT = ... :}
               expr:e1 MINUS expr:e2
               {: RESULT = ... :}
```

For the unary negation, I tried this

```
      |  MINUS expr:e               
         {: RESULT = - e; :}
         %prec UMINUS
```

, but it says that the negative sign is a bad operand type.

Is there any tips to do unary negation?

Comment: what parser generator are you using?

Comment: Unsure whether it’s what you are asking. `System.out.println(8 - - - 2 + 3);` works in my Java and prints `9`.

Comment: *What* says 'the negative sign is a bad operand type'? For which line?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne it says it one the line where it says {: RESULT = - e; :}.

Comment: @MauricePerry I am using jflex.

Comment: Irrelevant You haven't answered my question. JFlex generates scanners, and does not generate this message. Your question is about an expression grammar for a parser generator. Which?

Comment: @DLIM7 JFlex generates a lexer. It seems you're using CUP to generate the parser.